# Fetch either from local or from heroku/deployed server

Tags: angular, deployment

I work on my app locally, but after some task completed I deploy it on netlify to check how it goes.
I want to switch my fetch requests depending on where I serve the app (local/netlify)

Here is **my auth.service.ts**, which logic should I implement ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001'
const deployedUrl = 'https://my-deployed-server.herokuapp.com'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(user:any){
    return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/login`, user, {observe: "body", responseType:"json"})
  }

  signup(user:any){
    return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/signup`, user, {observe: "body", responseType:"json"})
  }
}
```

Thank for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create different `.env` files. In your project you should have folder named `enviorment` inside that folder you should have at least two files: `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` (you can add as many environment files as you like). Inside those files you can declare different variables. So in your case you have to create one more `env` files (i will assume that the heroku version will be your production enviorment).

// File environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api: 'https://my-deployed-server.herokuapp.com'
};
```

// File environment.dev.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api: 'localhost:{your-port here}'
};
```

after that in your service you will use env files as so

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { enviorment } from 'environments/environment'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(user:any){
    return this.http.post(`${enviorment.apiUrl}/login`, user, {observe: "body", responseType:"json"})
  }

  signup(user:any){
    return this.http.post(`${enviorment.apiUrl}/signup`, user, {observe: "body", responseType:"json"})
  }
}
```

Here the important thing is that you should import the `environment` variable from the base `environment` file (not .prod , .dev paths). Based on your build config the base environment file will be overwritten with some of the other  environment files. So if you build/serve your app for production the `apiUrl` will point to the remote server and if you build/serve for dev, the `apiUrl` will be `localhost`

You can learn more about the file replacement [here](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements) and about the build configurations [here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#alternate-build-configurations)

Comment: Thank you ! yes I have those environments files. Thank you for your help !